# How do I add a link between azure devops work item and a git branch with the node api?

Tags: node.js, git, azure, azure-devops

I am trying to update a work item in azure devops with a linked branch in my repo.  I'm using the azure-devops-node-api.  Currently i'm trying to update the field "relations", but im not sure thats correct.

```
   if (linkUrl) {
      azureUpdateArr.push({
        op: "add",
        path: "/relations/-",
        value: {
          rel: "ArtifactLink",
          url: linkUrl,
          attributes: {
            name: "Branch",
            comment: "Making a new link for the branch",
          },
        },
      });
    }

    await api.updateWorkItem({}, azureUpdateArr, Number(workItem.Number));
```

The `azureUpdateArr` is a json patch doc, so i'm just trying to add an operation to add a relation, but i'm not sure what the `rel:` should be, or indeed anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i'm not sure what the rel: should be, or indeed anything else.

Based on my test, if you need to link a git branch to the Work item , the `rel` type is `ArtifactLink`.

As is shown in your code, the `rel` could be correct.

I refer to this doc about Rest API: [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

Here is my Request Body sample:

```
{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "ArtifactLink",
      "url": "vstfs:///Git/Ref/{Project ID}/{Repo ID}/GB{Branch name}",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Branch",
        "comment": "test link branch"
      }
    }
  }
```

Result:

[image]

Note: you need to use `GB+Branch name` format in the url field. Or it seems that the branch couldn't be linked successfully.

Hope this helps.